# postgresql is active with pgadmin4 but not showing anything in my php code

Tags: package-management, apache2, php, postgresql, xampp

I'm new to ubuntu community or linux sounds better. so I don't have much knowledge of repositoies and packages. So, I've installed xampp, postgresql and pgadmin4 in my ubuntu 20.04 LTS. nothing showed me any error everything was smooth. my php codes are executing fine. the the problem came up when I tried to connect a database to my php code. for your refference I'm leaving the simple database connection code that I used to check whether my database is connecting to php or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>pg con</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    echo"something";
    $con=pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=testdb username=naeem password=naeem");
    if(!$con)
    {
        echo"error while connecting to database";
        echo "<br>";
        echo pg_last_error($con);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "connection to database successfull";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I tried to echo `"something"` before making a connection to database which is showing on the browser(firefox and chrome), But nothing appears after using `pg_connect()`.

Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image: see the output screen here]

Answer (score 0):

You will likely want to expand your PostgreSQL connection code to make use of `pg_last_error()` in addition to the check for a connection. This will give you a little more detail when something goes sideways:

```
if ( !$con || pg_last_error($con) ) {
    print_r("<h3>Error while connecting to database</h3>";
    print_r(pg_last_error($con));
} else {
    echo "<h3>Connection to database successful.</h3>";
}
```

One note regarding the connection string: if you are working with a full range of character sets (not just ASCII), you may want to include `options='--client_encoding=UTF8'` to ensure that there are no encoding issues between PHP and PostgreSQL. This will give you a connection string that looks like this:

```
host=[HOST] port=[PORT] dbname=[NAME] user=[USER] password=[PASS] options='--client_encoding=UTF8'
```